# C++ − Can a single parameter pack be expanded more than once in a single expression?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have a function which takes 3 template parameters : two types and an integer constant (used for Eigen storage requirements). It looks like the following template :

```cpp
template <typename VertexType, typename IndexType, Eigen::StorageOptions Options>
void my_big_function(/* 3 Eigen parameters depending on template args... */) {
    /* Do stuff with matrices... */
}
```

And since this function needs to be bound to python with multiple template "triplets", I thought this could be a nice use of [template parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

I want to achieve the following :

```cpp
// binds to python :
// - my_big_function<float, int, ColMajor>(...)
bind_my_big_function<float, int, Eigen::ColMajor>(m); // (1)
// binds to python :
// - my_big_function<float, int, ColMajor>(...)
// - my_big_function<float, int, RowMajor>(...)
// - my_big_function<double, int, RowMajor>(...)
bind_my_big_function<float, int, Eigen::ColMajor, float, int, Eigen::RowMajor, double, int, Eigen::RowMajor>(m); // (2)
```

Where `bind_my_big_function` is simple enough :

```cpp
template <typename MatVertexType, typename MatIndexType, Eigen::StorageOptions MatOptions, typename...RemainingArgs>
void bind_my_big_function(pybind11::module_& m) {
    /* bind function taking MatVertexType, MatIndexType & MatOptions and go onto binding other variants of my_big_function */
}
```

And while I can definitely produce some code that handles case (1), I cannot figure out how to write code that handles case (2). The closest I got was something like this :

```cpp
template <typename MatVertexType, typename MatIndexType, Eigen::StorageOptions MatOptions>
void bind_my_big_function(pybind11::module_& m) {
    m.def("my_big_function_in_python", &my_big_function<MatVertexType, MatIndexType, MatOptions>, /* python arguments...*/);
}

template <
    typename MatVertexType, typename MatIndexType, Eigen::StorageOptions MatOptions,
    typename...RemainingArgs, typename = typename std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(RemainingArgs) != 0>
>
void bind_my_big_function(pybind11::module_& m) {
    m.def("my_big_function_in_python", &my_big_function<MatVertexType, MatIndexType, MatOptions>, /* python arguments...*/);
    bind_my_big_function<RemainingArgs...>(m);
}
```

Are parameter packs supposed to be used in this way ? Only examples I could find of their use was either :

- with templated function arguments,
- with a single pack expansion "usage" at a time (the called function required only one type and a variadic template pack)

Comment: You cannot capture **None Type Template Parameter** (`Eigen::StorageOptions MatOptions`) as `typename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (yet) capture mixed type (`MatVertexType`, `MatIndexType`) and non-type (`MatOptions`) template parameters in a single pack, since as of C++23 a pack has to be of a single kind: type (`typename`/`class`), `template`, or value (concrete or `auto`).

There are a couple of possible solutions:

1. Lift the non-type template parameter to type space, using e.g. `std::integral_constant<Eigen::StorageOption>`, so that it can be passed inside a type pack alongside the type parameters;
2. Combine each triple of related parameters into a single type e.g. `template<class MatVertexType, class MatIndexType, Eigen::StorageOption MatOptions> struct MatParameters;` (this is the AOS option);
3. (as in your solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/77488183/567292) Pass three homogeneous packs, using e.g. `std::tuple` for type packs and `std::integer_sequence` (in type space) or `std::array` (in value space) for value packs (this is the SOA variant of option 2);
4. Wait for "[Universal Template Parameters](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1985r3.pdf)", which has been proposed for C++26.

Comment: I already have come to a solution, which I posted in the answers which is basically a different version of (3.) that you propose. I have three tuple-like structures which I iterate on thanks to recursive function calls.

Comment: A couple questions remain, though : If I lift a constant using `std::integer_constant` and get only type names in the template pack, I still cannot iterate on it 3 items at a time, right ? Do I have to provide partial specializations in case the pack is expanded from the second item of a sub sequence onward, or does providing a single partial specialization using 3 template parameters and a parameter pack suffice?

Comment: @ThibaultdeVillèle yes, to consume multiple pack elements at a time you have to use recursion or some equivalent technique. A single function template that checks whether to recurse using `if constexpr (sizeof...(Rest) != 0)` is probably the cleanest option.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question, but if you want to instantiate some `foo<Ts...,Ts...,Ts...>` given `Ts...` you can wrap the function template and just have to instantiate it:

```
template <typename ...Ts>
void foo() {};

template <typename ...Ts>
void foo_expand() {
    foo<Ts...,Ts...,Ts...>();
};
```

Comment: The problem seems to stem from the fact I'm mixing typenames and well-defined classes/types : the compiler throws an error on the second use case in my OP because a `Eigen::StorageOption` enum is being matched with a typename. It seems like the parameter pack is not actually being expanded 3 items at a time, but rather one item at a time.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of other people trying to do the same, here's what I ended up doing.

I packed each argument of the template "triplets" into tuple-like empty structs, and performed the pack expansion using recursive calls on the tuples. Here is a rough skeleton of the resulting code :

```cpp
template <typename... Types> struct type_tuple {};
template <Eigen::StorageOptions...> struct eigen_storage_tuple {};

template <typename VertexType, typename IndexType, Eigen::StorageOptions Options>
constexpr void bind(pybind11::module_& m) {
    /* Bind the current template of my_big_func() given params above: */
    m.def(/* ... */);
}

template <
    typename VertexType, template <typename> class VertexTypeTuple,
    typename IndexType, template <typename> class IndexTypeTuple,
    Eigen::StorageOptions Options, template <Eigen::StorageOptions> class OptionTypeTuple
>
constexpr void bind_recursively(
    pybind11::module_& m,
    const VertexTypeTuple<VertexType> vertex_types,
    const IndexTypeTuple<IndexType> index_types,
    const OptionTypeTuple<Options> option_type
) {
    bind<VertexType, IndexType, Options>(m);
}

template <
    typename VertexType, typename... VertexTypes, template <typename, typename...> class VertexTypeTuple,
    typename IndexType, typename... IndexTypes, template <typename, typename...> class IndexTypeTuple,
    Eigen::StorageOptions Option, Eigen::StorageOptions... Options, template <Eigen::StorageOptions, Eigen::StorageOptions...> class OptionsTypeTuple
>
constexpr void bind_recursively(
    pybind11::module_& m,
    const VertexTypeTuple<VertexType, VertexTypes...> vertex_types,
    const IndexTypeTuple<IndexType, IndexTypes...> index_types,
    const OptionsTypeTuple<Option, Options...> options
) {
    VertexTypeTuple<VertexType> current_vertex_type;
    IndexTypeTuple<IndexType> current_index_type;
    OptionsTypeTuple<Option> current_option;

    VertexTypeTuple<VertexTypes...> remaining_vertex_type;
    IndexTypeTuple<IndexTypes...> remaining_index_type;
    OptionsTypeTuple<Options...> remaining_option;

    bind_recursively(m, current_vertex_type, current_index_type, current_option);
    bind_recursively(m, remaining_vertex_type, remaining_index_type, remaining_option);
}
```

All the tuple arguments in the function calls are there only for overload resolution and pack expansions.

Because each parameter pack is surrounded by a "concrete" type in the recursive bind function, I am able to iterate on all three packs and generate all calls to `pybind11::module_::def()` at compile time. Here is an example of how to call that function and resolve all calls :

```cpp
constexpr type_tuple<
    float, float, float, float, /* For col major types */
    float, float, float, float, /* For row major types */
    double, double, double, double, /* For col major types */
    double, double, double, double  /* For row major types */
> remove_unused_vertices_vertex_types;
constexpr type_tuple<
    std::int32_t, std::uint32_t, std::int64_t, std::uint64_t, /* For col major types */
    std::int32_t, std::uint32_t, std::int64_t, std::uint64_t, /* For row major types */
    std::int32_t, std::uint32_t, std::int64_t, std::uint64_t, /* For col major types */
    std::int32_t, std::uint32_t, std::int64_t, std::uint64_t  /* For row major types */
> remove_unused_vertices_index_types;
constexpr eigen_storage_tuple<
    Eigen::StorageOptions::ColMajor, Eigen::StorageOptions::ColMajor, Eigen::StorageOptions::ColMajor, Eigen::StorageOptions::ColMajor,
    Eigen::StorageOptions::RowMajor, Eigen::StorageOptions::RowMajor, Eigen::StorageOptions::RowMajor, Eigen::StorageOptions::RowMajor,
    Eigen::StorageOptions::ColMajor, Eigen::StorageOptions::ColMajor, Eigen::StorageOptions::ColMajor, Eigen::StorageOptions::ColMajor,
    Eigen::StorageOptions::RowMajor, Eigen::StorageOptions::RowMajor, Eigen::StorageOptions::RowMajor, Eigen::StorageOptions::RowMajor
> remove_unused_vertices_storage_orders;

bind_recursively(
    cull_module,
    remove_unused_vertices_vertex_types,
    remove_unused_vertices_index_types,
    remove_unused_vertices_storage_orders
);

/* Will bind all combinations of the vertex, index, and storage order types given above. */
```